# Expandable ListView inside swipe refresh layout doesn't work

Tags: android

I am trying to apply swipe refresh in expandable listView, when the list view is scrolled to bottom and I try to scroll up, then it doesn't scroll up, the swipe refresh layout activates, How to solve this problem? any idea.!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
expandableListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        int topRowVerticalPosition = (expandableListView == null || expandableListView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : expandableListView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(firstVisibleItem == 0 && topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
    }
});
```